# SQL Server : how to convert float yyyymmdd to date yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In other posts you advice to use

```
TO_DATE(your_date as String, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

but in SQL Server there is no function `to_date` :(

I tried something like this:

```
select 
    start_date2 = replace(substring(cast(start_date as varchar),1,5),'.','') + '-' +
        case when substring(cast(start_date as char),6,2) ='1e' then '10' else substring(cast(start_date as char),6,2) end + '-' +
        cast(substring(cast(start_date as char),8,2)as char)
from 
    my_table
```

but it returns for example:

```
1971-05-e+
```

instead of:

```
1971-05-08
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the original data type is actually float, this can be done with multiple castings:

```
DECLARE @Date float = 19710508

SELECT  CAST(
            CAST(
                CAST(@Date as int) 
            as char(8)) 
        as date)
```

Result (date data type):

```
1971-05-08
```

The inner cast removes all the digits after the decimal point,
The middle cast converts the int value to a char value, since explicit cast from int to date is not allowed, and the outer cast converts the char value to date.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @input FLOAT = 20160725

SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, CAST(CAST(@input AS INT) AS CHAR(8)), 112)
```

We need to CAST to INT because we want to remove zero numbers after decimal point, something like this `value = 20160725.000000.`

Comment: Do you make sure that your data is always yyyymmdd?